# Bad bone rotation in Unity humanoid

Tags: rigging, bones, unity

It looks that I can not export roll setting from Blender to Unity, because it still has bad rotation. I tried different axis, different roll, blend file, fbx file. Nothing is working.

It is working good with generic animation, but with humanoid it is bad.

Blender:
[image]

Unity:

[image]

Comment: Are you using an .fbx export? If you're using a set driven key, and exporting an .fbx, set driven keys don't work with an .fbx.

Comment: I tried FBX and also Blend, I am not using driven keys